# GNOME Boxes: proper network configuration?

Tags: networking, gnome, virtual-machine, gnome-boxes

I've got a problem with GNOME Boxes:

I've 2 machines, cloned 1 from other, with CentOS. Both machines get same IP address on GNOME Boxes, so when I boot the 2nd, the 1st gets disconnected from network, and vice versa. This is not acceptable behaviour, and I've been struggling to find out why does this happen for quite some time.

Comment: What version of GNOME Boxes was that? The current version (at least 3.38.1) assigns a different MAC address by default when cloning a virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've found out is that Gnome Boxes & Libvirt save mac-address for machines in config located here:

```
/home/$USER/.config/libvirt/qemu
```

So, to fix the issue, both machines must have different Mac-addresses, which can be fixed only by editing those files. Didn't find any relevant option in Gnome Boxes GUI.

Comment: It should be also possible to change `<mac address="…"/>` value in GNOME Boxes (at least in version 3.38.1) in the VM's properties → system → edit XML.